# using 'quite a' with adjective 'vulnerable'

Tags: phrase-usage, adjectives, style

Is it okay to use the modifier 'quite a' with adjective 'vulnerable' in referense to children?

I've been using "quite a vulnerable boy" for a very long time and have always found this phrase useful for writing reports on kindergarten boys that can easily get hurt.

However, I just entered the phrase "quite a vulnerable boy" in Google and found... [only 2 results!](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=bmv5XO3HGsOK8gXr35jQDg&q=%22quite%20a%20vulnerable%20boy%22&oq=%22quite%20a%20vulnerable%20boy%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i302i39.11601.12444..13482...0.0..0.55.333.7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.GWPi6DCDjj0) This looks very suspicious. Before, I would enter even more refined quires and would get hundreds of different results. Is something wrong with that phrase? Perhaps, not in terms of grammar, but in terms of style?

Comment: _He’s quite a good soccer player._ that's from LDOCE5, so your phrase should be fine, imo

Comment: @MvLog - But my question is not about "good", but about "vulnerable".

Comment: Does it matter? The structure is the same.

Comment: @MvLog - I've run into many cases when the structure was absolutely the same, but due to some other linguistic parameters (style, word's usage, etc.) my phrase was not fine at all.

Comment: That's true, but you cannot expect a non-native to remember all arbitrary collocations in English. If no one openly objects—then it goes, imo. Not a native myself, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems fine to me (native British English speaker).

I believe that "quite" meaning "somewhat" (which I think is the only reasonable reading of this) is mostly a British usage: American English prefers "quite" only in the sense of "very, completely".

In possible support of this, searching the GloWbE corpus for "quite a [adjective]" gives 4501 hits for UK, but only 1484 for US (1429 for AU, and each other variety less than 1000).

Answer (score 1):

"He's quite a vulnerable boy" is perfectly fine, though it may strike some as a bit stilted. "He's a very vulnerable boy" means the same thing and will sound more natural to many native speakers.

Edit: Well, now that I've read Colin Fine's answer, I guess I should say "he's a very vulnerable boy" means the same thing as "he's quite a vulnerable boy" in *American* English. It seems the two are far from equivalent in British English!